# How to define an integer vector containing scientific notation correctly in C++?

Tags: c++, scientific-notation, narrowing

The code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main () { std::vector<int> N = {3e6, 4e6}; }
```

Gives an error

```
error: narrowing conversion of ‘3.0e+6’ from ‘double’ to ‘int’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]|||.
```

Whereas

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main () {
   std::vector<int> N = {3*10^6, 4*10^6};
   for (int n: N ){ std::cout << n << std::endl; }
}
```

prints

```
24
46.
```

How to define this vector as an integer vector correctly?

If have found while writing this question that setting

```
int n1 = 3e6, n2 = 4e6;
vector<int> N = {n1, n2};
```

does work, but is there a better way? The type is still converted from double to int in declarations of n1 and n2.

Comment: You do know that C++ does not have an exponentiation operator? `^` is not doing what you want it to do.

Comment: As the error explains, scientific notation produces `double`s. If you are sure your values are representable as `int`, you can just cast them to `int`.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Yes, I know that after doing the example above. I thought that it might be useful to other noobs like me who might stumble upon this question later so wrote it up as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on using that notation, you can perform an explicit cast to shut the compiler up, but it's not a good idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main () { std::vector<int> N = {int(3e6), int(4e6)}; }
```

Comment: Can you clarify why is it not a good idea? In my view 3e6 has the advantage that it is easier to distinguish from 3e7 than distinguishing 3000000 from 30000000. Of course, 3'000'000 is the c++14 way to do it...

Comment: @Andre Because things like `int(3e21)` compile without warning, but almost certainly don't do what you are expecting.

Comment: @Andre Telling the compiler to shut up with a cast is never a good idea. It usually hides the problem but does not fix it.

Comment: I have the same opinion as @Andre and thought that there must be a better way without getting confused by all the zeroes.